# How to check if a dependency is satisfiable or not

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I want to check, using a script, if a dependency of a package is satisfiable.

I'm not checking if it is installed, just installable. I'm not trying to install a package. I'm also not asking how to fix or resolve issues with dependencies. I just need my function to answer yes or no.

For example:

```
somepackage (= 11.0.6-4)
anotherone (>> 1.1.2)
yetanother (>= 1.0.16)
andanother (>= 1:2.8.0)
```

For the first one, I can do an `apt-get --simulate install somepackage=11.0.6-4` and see if it fails. For the others, apt-get does not have a feature to install >= or strictly >>.

Also, what if my repos has something like `11.0.6-4ubuntu1` or some PPA string like `11.0.6-4ubuntu1~ubuntu20.04.1~ppa1`? In my tests the equal sign will fail even if it is acceptable as a dependency by apt.

For the others, I'm thinking of using `apt-cache policy` and checking the `Candidate:` line and doing a numerical comparison. This will fail though for version numbers like 1:2.8.0 where the actual version there is 2.8.0 and not 1. Also, Candidate gives the newest version, which may not always be the desired version.

It's also possible that apt will say "this package is not available but this package provides it" or "installing package1 instead of package2" which makes my manual comparison wrong.

Hence, I want to do this in a way that is consistent with how APT compares packages and version numbers. I don't want my manual comparisons to have false positives or false negatives. I might end up installing something that would cause a broken system, or on the other hand, rejecting to install something that is otherwise installable. Even better if I can tap the apt system itself to tell my if my repos satisfy the needed packages and versions.

Some programs can do this, so I think what I want is doable. If I open a deb package in gdebi, it tells me if there are unsatisfiable dependencies. Gdebi says `Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: packagename (>= 1:2.8.0)`. Basically I would want to do what gdebi does.

Comment: On a basic level, you could use the `--dry-run` flag on the `apt install` command and `grep` for a dependency error.

Comment: `--dry-run` is a synonym of `--simulate` which I mentioned above. How would I do, for example, an `apt install --simulate packagename (>= 1:2.8.0)` ? It's possible that I have packagename in my repos but a diifferent version.

Comment: Gdebi asks apt for the information (it's in the source code), and apt does all the solving. Gdebi is written in Python3, so not too hard to decipher how to query apt.

Comment: Do you have said package at hand as a .deb file? I guess you could simply `apt install -s ./package.deb` then.

Comment: @danzel `apt install` doesn't work on deb files, it only works on package names in a repository. Also, `-s` is a synonym for `--simulate` which I've discussed already. Also, I'm not trying to install a package. I want to check, using a script, if a dependency of a package is satisfiable.

Comment: @user535733 Yes, I would prefer if apt does all the solving. I'll check out the gdebi source to see how it queries apt.

Comment: @bamm `apt install` has worked on local deb files for several years now, replacing the need for gdebi in many circumstances. The format is `apt install /path/to/file.deb`. The older apt-get application cannot handle local filenames.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for the information. I didn't know that it worked now. Denzel was right after all. However, that is not my question. I think the answer lies in your suggestion for me to study the gdebi source.

Comment: @bamm It's not really clear to me what exactly you want to achieve. Checking if each individual dependency has an installation candidate doesn't really tell you if all dependencies are satisfiable. You also didn't tell us what kind of script you are looking for (bash? python?...)

Comment: @danzel I'm not looking for a script. I'm writing a script. In my script, I'm writing a function. I want my function to tell me if `packagename (>= 1:2.8.0)` is satisfiable on a given system or not. Gdebi can do this, so I know it's doable.

Comment: For example, if `packagename (>= 1:2.8.0)` is provided by `newerpackage` with a different name, then it is considered satisfiable, even if packagename itself may have no installation candidate.

Comment: @user535733 I think I hit a dead end. The gdebi source calls `import apt` and `import apt.debfile`. It seems to be using some python functions that do the heavy lifting. No where in the script did it make a call to an external executable such as apt-get.

Comment: @bamm `gdebi` uses python3 bindings for `libapt`, which are e.g. provided by the package `python3-apt`. More specifically, it uses the class `apt.debfile.DebPackage`, which, like `gdebi` or `apt`, requires a specific debian package to work with. `gdebi`, like `apt`, tells you if _all_ dependencies of a _specific_ package are satisfiable. To be honest, I still can't imagine any use case for your desired function.